# Where can user inform Ubuntu Snap Store to update snap from third-party?

Tags: snap, update-alternatives

Where can user inform Ubuntu Snap Store to update snap from third-party?

Example: Oracle provide VirtualBox latest statble version for Ubuntu.

But Ubuntu SnapStore provide old version.

So Where can user inform Ubuntu Snap Store to update such snaps or such software?

Answer (score 0):

## Via the CLI

If an application is a snap, you can find the contact info of the third-party publisher by running `snap info snap-name`.

```
$ snap info foliate
name:      foliate
summary:   A simple and modern eBook viewer
publisher: John Factotum (johnfactotum)
store-url: https://snapcraft.io/foliate
contact:   https://github.com/johnfactotum/foliate/issues
license:   GPL-3.0+
description: |
...
```

The `contact` field shows you how to contact the publisher.

## Via the Snap Store website.

1. Go to https://snapcraft.io/store
2. Search for the snap
3. Go to the listing page of the snap and click on the "Contact" link below the description.

## Snap Not found?

If you can't find the snap in the online snap store, that means it comes from the regular Ubuntu APT repositories. These can only be updated together with Ubuntu itself, so either you upgrade to a newer Ubuntu release, or you contact the developer of the application and ask them to create a Snap.

VirtualBox, for example, is not available as a Snap yet.

## Contact info not found?

Some publishers have not filled in the contact info for the Snap. In that case, you will have to use Google to find who is responsible for the Snap.